# $n$ letters in $n$ envelopes

Tags: probability, random-variables

A secretary introduces randomly 9 letters in 9 envelopes. Let $X$ be the random variable representing the number of letters that have matched the correct envelopes. Find $E(X)$ and $var(X)$

I know the solution for "the probability that none is in the correct envelope" and "the probability that at least one is in the correct envelope", but I don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $i=1,2,\dots,9$ let $X_i$ take value $1$ if letter $i$ lands in the correct envelop and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Then:$$X=\sum_{i=1}^9X_i$$

With linearity of expectation and symmetry we find:$$\mathsf EX=\sum_{i=1}^9\mathsf EX_i=9\mathsf EX_1$$

Can you find $\mathsf EX_1$ yourself?

Further on base of bilinearity of covariance and symmetry we find:$$\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)=\sum_{i=1}^9\sum_{j=1}^9\mathsf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=9\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_1)+72\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$$

Can you find $\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_1)=\mathsf{Var}(X_1)$ and $\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$ yourself?

Comment: I am used to writing random variables like i -> P(i) where P is a probability function. In your example, $E(X1)$ means the expectancy that the first letter lands in the correct envelope ? so $1/2$ ?

Comment: $X_1$ can only take values $0$ and $1$ so that $\mathsf EX_1=0\cdot P(X_1=0)+1\cdot P(X_1=1)=P(X_1=1)=\frac19$. What makes you think that it is $\frac12$?

Comment: Could you please explain why $\mathsf{Var}(X)=\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)=\sum_{i=1}^9\sum_{j=1}^9\mathsf{Cov}(X_i,X_j)=9\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_1)+72\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$ ? I don't know of this formula... I have found that $Cov(X_1, X_1) = 1/9 - 1/81$ but I don't know how to find $\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)$

Comment: @Liviu the way you are used to corresponds to the method I posted. But if you can understand drhab's method, that's more efficient.

Comment: Do you understand that $\mathsf{Cov}(X+Y,Z)=\mathsf{Cov}(X,Z)+\mathsf{Cov}(Y,Z)$? Just work out the definition of covariance. Also $\mathsf{Cov}(X+Y,Z)=\mathsf{Cov}(Z,X+Y)$ so linearity works on the other side as well. Based on these facts you can prove what I wrote in my answer. Your calculation of $\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_1)$ is correct.

Comment: $\mathsf{Cov}(X_1,X_2)=\mathsf EX_1X_2-\mathsf EX_1\mathsf EX_2$. Here $\mathsf EX_1X_2=P(X_1=1=X_2)$ which is the probability that two distinct letters land in the correct envelop: $P(\text{first lands well})P(\text{second lands well}\mid\text{first lands well})=\frac19\frac18$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Thank you, I will try to understand this though, as it seems more simple to me.

Comment: @drhab Thank you so much !

Comment: You are very welcome. Beware.. if only expectation (and eventually variance) is asked for then first try to solve it without calculation of distribution. That can save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

To build a permutation that fixes $k$ elements, you have to first choose these $k$ elements:
$${9\choose k }\text{ options}$$
Then you have to choose a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the remaining $9-k$:
$$!(9-k)\text{ options}$$

The expected value is therefore $$E=\sum_\limits{k=0}^9k\times\dfrac{ !(9-k)\times {9\choose k }}{9!}$$
and the variance $$\left(\sum_\limits{k=0}^9k^2\times\dfrac{ !(9-k)\times {9\choose k }}{9!}\right)-E^2$$

Comment: This directs to calculation of distribution. The OP only has to find expectation and variance. This can be done by means of distribution, but must be discouraged in this situation.

Comment: @drhab It may be better in a way, but it's always good to have several points of view at hand. Plus I'd be happy if my students were only able to do this.

Comment: Well, so be it. But the fact that I sincerely hope that this method is *not used* prevents me from upvoting (i.e. saying that it is useful).

Comment: @drhab sure, I perfectly understand :) I did upvote your post for the opposite reason.